# Confused to use join or sub-query SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Table1

```
Id Name  DemoID
1  a      33
2  b      44
3  c      33
4  d      33
5  e      44
```

Table2

```
Id DemoID IsTrue
11  33     1  
12  44     1
```

Now we can find which DemoID is present in Table2 using below 2 queries using join and using sub-query, but which is more accurate/relevant for more number of records?

using join -

```
SELECT Table1.Id FROM Table1  Table1 join Table2 Table2 on Table1.DemoID  = Table2.DemoID 
WHERE Table2.IsTrue = 1
```

using sub-query -

```
SELECT Table1.Id  FROM Table1  Table1
WHERE Table1.DemoID  in (select Table2.DemoID from Table2 Table2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but which is more accurate / relevant for more number of records ?

Neither and both. The optimizer is free to rewrite subqueries as joins.

For clarity, since you don't need any columns from `Table2`, I'd go with a third option and use `EXISTS`.

This is only a benefit for the reader in this case. In other cases, writing a join may result in unwanted row duplication, which will typically lead someone to add a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to remove them, which are unnecessary with `EXISTS` or `IN...`

Of course, it's different with `NOT IN`. If `NULL`s exist in the relation, you'll get an empty result set. This can be quite confusing to beginning query writers.

As a style choice, I go with `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` when I'm referencing a subquery, and `IN`/`NOT IN` when I have a list of literal values.

Hope this helps!